# Query tuning for update of large volumes of data

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, plsql, oracle12c

I have a huge dataset which grows everyday. There is a certain update which is run on the data for each and every row.

```
Table Structure :
Id    Level   Data     Output
--    -----   -------  --------- 
1     1         12.3      12.3
1     2         42.5     522.75
1     3        129     67434.75
2     1          3.12      3.12
2     2          0.12      0.3744
2     3         32.1      12.01824
2     4         39.1     469.913184
3     1          0.83      0.83
3     2          4.21      3.4943
4     1          3.49      3.49
```

For one id, the output is the multiplication of the data with the data of its previous levels [data*1 for level = 1]

Now, there is no limit to the number of ids that are obtained each day and neither to the number of levels for each.

Edited :: Help calculate output (values or as column) for this data set.

Comment: Please confirm that `output` is a column on the table, i.e. this is an update not  a query. Also, how often do you want to run this ?

Comment: It's impossible to tune a query that we don't see. **[edit]** your question and add the query, the definition of the table and all indexes (as `create` statements) and the query plan. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: could you help me with possible ways to calculate the output column?

Comment: hope this ends the ambiguity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data in a record should not depend on data in other records. With `output` being the running product of `data` per ID, this should not be stored, but queried. (Otherwise you'd have to recalculate all values whenever an update on `data` occurs.) We must strive to avoid redundancy in our database in order to avoid consistency issues.

Having said this, you'd have to write a query. One option would be a recursive query. Another would be a window function. As to the latter, there is `SUM OVER` and `AVG OVER` etc. but no `MULTIPLY OVER` or the like. So we'd have to create this aggregation function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE AggregateProduct 
AS OBJECT 
(
  product NUMBER,

  STATIC FUNCTION ODCIAggregateInitialize(actx IN OUT AggregateProduct) RETURN NUMBER,
  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateIterate(self  IN OUT AggregateProduct, val IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER,
  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateTerminate(self IN AggregateProduct, returnValue OUT NUMBER, flags IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER,
  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateMerge(self IN OUT AggregateProduct, ctx2 IN AggregateProduct) RETURN NUMBER
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY AggregateProduct AS
  STATIC FUNCTION ODCIAggregateInitialize(actx IN OUT AggregateProduct) RETURN NUMBER IS 
  BEGIN
    IF actx IS NULL THEN
      actx := AggregateProduct(null);
    ELSE
      actx.product := null;
    END IF;
    RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
  END;

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateIterate(self IN OUT AggregateProduct, val IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS
  BEGIN
    IF val IS NOT NULL THEN
      self.product := NVL(self.product, 1) * val;
    END IF;
    RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
  END;

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateTerminate(self IN AggregateProduct, ReturnValue OUT NUMBER, flags IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS
  BEGIN
    returnValue := self.product;
    RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
  END;

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateMerge(self IN OUT AggregateProduct, ctx2 IN AggregateProduct) RETURN NUMBER IS
  BEGIN
    self.product := self.product * ctx2.product;
    RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
  END;
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION agg_multiply(x NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER PARALLEL_ENABLE
  AGGREGATE USING AggregateProduct;
```

The query would then be:

```
select 
  id, "level", data,
  agg_multiply(data) over(partition by id order by "level") as output
from mytable
order by id, "level";
```

(You should avoid `level` for a column name by the way, as this is a reserved word in Oracle.)

The other option, as mentioned, would be a recursive query, but where would be the fun in that? ;-)

```
multiplied(id, "level", data, output) as
(
  select id, "level", data, data as output from mytable where "level" = 1
  union all
  select mytable.id, mytable."level", mytable.data, mytable.data * multiplied.output
  from multiplied
  join mytable on mytable.id = multiplied.id and mytable."level" = multiplied."level" + 1
)
select * 
from multiplied 
order by id, "level";
```

Comment: thanks... though I still am worried about the performance with the huge volumes of data....

Comment: But usually you query just part of the data, e.g. data for a certain ID, not the whole table, or do you?

Comment: it is for a part of data but that part is quite complex... like same id can have multiple levels.. for id 1, there can more than 1 record for level 2 and so on

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure that, always running same query for update?
2. If yes, you should be create materialized view against the query that help optimization, because when any query execute it will search in materialized view.
3. When compare level-should be create index of level column.

Comment: A materialized view doesn't solve the problem of calculating the updated `output` values in an optimal fashion.

Comment: materialized view will also be very heavy considering I get around 50 Lakh records in the table every day.

Comment: Day by day it will be huge level of data or greater then billion then need the optimization for performance issue. If you have execute same query then need to be put in buffer area of your query statement. where a don't effect physical memory and segment.

Comment: @Amran - this is a functional process but need to re-write it since it is going to become a problem soon due to the excessive record count.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the table you mentioned using a composite key.

1. Create Single Index having this 2 column.
2. Use Oracle Hint to direct the optimizer using your index.

   ```
   Update  /*+ INDEX(tabName indexName) */ tabName
   set column = value
   where id = 1 and level = 1
   ```

Thanks a lot to APC for enlighten what its trying to achieve.
Maybe I should put example to be more clear

```
   Update  /*+ INDEX(tabName indexName) */ tabA t1
   set output = data * exp(sum(log(select data from tabA t2 where t2.level < t1.level)
   where id = 1 and level = 3
```

Not sure will hit table locking or not since we try to select the table while update

Comment: That's not the problem they're trying to solve. When record `(1,1)` is updated that value must be rippled down through  `(1,2) ,(1,3),(1,4)...(1,n)`. Maybe your index will make that more efficient but it's a guess.

Comment: I need to update the output column only. As in calculate it and re-calculate it if values change.